# MySQL query running slowly

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I got this query working but it's really slow.

I want with this query: 1 random `(id,word,meaning)` and 1 random incorrect any another word meaning. How can I get better performance with my query?

```
$offset_result = mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM words WHERE APPROVAL=1 AND PERIOD<".$_SESSION['statistics']['d']." OR ( PERIOD=".$_SESSION['statistics']['d']."  AND WEEK<=".$_SESSION['statistics']['h'].")");
    $offset_row = mysql_fetch_object($offset_result);
    $offset = $offset_row->offset;  
    $words = mysql_query("SELECT ID,WORD,MEANING,
    (SELECT MEANING FROM words WHERE ID!=w.ID AND APPROVAL=1 AND WORD!=w.WORD AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(w.MEANING, OTHER_MEANING) AND ID >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(ID) * RAND()) FROM words) ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1) AS INCORRECT 
    FROM words w 
    LIMIT $offset, 1");
```

Here is the table layout

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    APPROVAL tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    WORD varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
    MEANING varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
    OTHER_MEANING varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
    PERIOD tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    WEEK tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    KEY APPROVAL (APPROVAL) ) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=769 ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question completely, but you can use `SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to get a random row from the result.

Comment: So what's your database schema and what indexes have you set in place?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: @PetrR. rand() slowly work. look this source [link](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/)

Comment: @AndyLester you are right. but my english not good. for this i know very well that i can not referrer my problem. i wrote my mysql table above. 2 time i need random loop. first time (wordID, word, word meaning) second time i need different word meaning. now in database have 769  data, but soon posible near to 20.000 word inserting. i use this system with true-false word quiz.  now my query in 768 data return 0,002-0,007 ms. i need better performance. sorry for my english.

Comment: @elTurko: that is pretty unreadable.  I edited your question and put the table layout in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is the `!=` and the `not in` clause.  If you rewrite this to not use these functions you will be better off.

[guide](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

> Summary
>
> MySQL can optimize all three methods to do a sort of NESTED LOOPS ANTI
>   JOIN.
>
> It will take each value from t_left and look it up in the index on
>   t_right.value. In case of an index hit or an index miss, the
>   corresponding predicate will immediately return FALSE or TRUE,
>   respectively, and the decision to return the row from t_left or not
>   will be made immediately without examining other rows in t_right.
>
> However, these three methods generate three different plans which are
>   executed by three different pieces of code. The code that executes
>   EXISTS predicate is about 30% less efficient than those that execute
>   index_subquery and LEFT JOIN optimized to use Not exists method.
>
> That’s why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using
>   a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET(w.MEANING, OTHER_MEANING)!=1` and `NOT FIND_IN_SET(w.MEANING, OTHER_MEANING)` between i think not have any different performance.